# How can be set the ember.js input name by model attribute?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a tabular form created in emberjs. 
I need to set the inputs name but it doesn't work.

my model:

```
Items.Item = DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   itemName: function() {
       return 'Item['+ this.id +'][title]';
   }
});
```

my original input

```
<td>{{input name="Item[][title]" value=qty}}</td>
```

and the code with the itemName:

```
<td>{{input name=itemName value=qty}}</td>
```

This doesn't work for me. if I put the itemName to the `value` attribute, it works, but with the name doesn't.

How can I set the name attribute?

It would be also good for me to set the name of the items in `each` loop with the `{{@index}}`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have modified the model this way:

```
itemName: function() {
   return 'Item['+ this.id +'][title]';
}.property()
```

and everything works...